# Integrate several WSO2 Identity Server by one IS

Tags: wso2, identity, wso2-identity-server

I have several different WSO2 Identity servers with different store of users in several companies. I can't remove them or make only one instead of them.

Now I need to make main WSO2IS server that would be integrate all of them to one. So users of one of source IS can be auth by there server and by main server.

How I can do this task?

Comment: I have a suggestion. So let's make the all the non-primary IS servers as Federated Identity Providers in the primary IS. Thereafter configure them as  options in the authentication steps for each app in primary IS. 
So when a user tried to login, he can either login with Primary IS or select any other IS server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found next link with same information:
https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS510/Login+to+the+Identity+Server+Using+Another+Identity+Server+-+SAML2

Thank you farasath for comment.